# Designing referentially transparent function for reading from channel

Tags: scala, io, functional-programming, scalaz, scala-cats

I'm trying to adhere to pure-FP style and want to design a referentially transparent function.

I have a `java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel`, which is a data source. And soon as I open a file and get the `SeekableFileChannel` instance, I need to read the first lines of the file and use these lines to determine the seek position.

So I created the following function:

```
object AdjustChannelAndGetStream {

  def apply(ch: SeekableFileChannel)
           (firstChunksToOffset: List[Array[Byte]] => Long): fs2.Stream[Id, Array[Byte]] {
    val offset = //depending on the first bytes read from the file 
                 //get the number of bytes read before
    val newChannel = ch.position(offset)
    //finally wrap newChannel into fs2.Stream
  }
}
```

The thing is, the function looks ugly. It does not suspend side effects, which makes it difficult to test (mocking `SeekableByteChannel`).

I tend to wrap `SeekableByteChannel` into `IO[SeekableByteChannel]` (Scalaz/Cats does not matter), but I don't see how it can help (we need the same `mock` of `SeekableByteChannel`, but now wrapped into `IO`).

Can you help me to design this function in pure-FP style (or at least to make it not so ugly)?

Comment: *I tend to wrap SeekableByteChannel into IO[SeekableByteChannel], but I don't see how it can help* - Wrapping it in IO would achieve exactly what you want, to defer the side effect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you need to wrap impure code, most of the time (based on my experience), it's not going to "be pretty". But, what we gain is that we only have a single point which deals with the "messy stuff", and we get a nice abstraction from there on.

What we want is to create a stream which is bound by an `IO` effect. Instead of `Stream[Id, SeekableByteChannel]`, we're really in `Stream[IO, SeekableByteChannel]` because we are in the `IO` effect context:

```
import java.nio.channels.SeekableByteChannel
import cats.effect.IO

object AdjustChannelAndGetStream {
    def apply(ch: SeekableByteChannel)(
        firstChunksToOffset: List[Array[Byte]] => Long)
      : fs2.Stream[IO, SeekableByteChannel] = {
      fs2.Stream.eval {
        IO {
          val offset: Int = ???
          ch.position(offset)
        }
      }
    }
}
```

This way, we suspend the side effect, which is what we want to make these side effectful computation RT, and apply transformations on the stream from this point on.

Comment: But how can I than map `fs2.Stream[IO, SeekableByteChannel]` to `fs2.Stream[IO, Array[Byte]]`. We don't have sort of `flatMap` here. I can use `fs2.io.readInputStream` but this seems does not help here because we are in the `IO` context. Or I missed something?

Comment: @SomeName We can also use `fs2.io.readInputStream` after consuming the `SeekableByteChannel` and exposing an `Array[Byte]` if that's what you want?